# Cant center UILabel in titleView of navigationItem iOS8

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem, titleview

Im having trouble setting a programmatically allocated `UILabel` to be centered in my NavigationItem's titleView. Im even setting the NSAlignment to be NSAlignmentCenter. Here's an image of what it looks like:

[image]

As you can see.. I have no right UIBarButtonItem in use, but this shouldn't be keeping the text from being centered?  Here's the code, in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
//Set the title of navBar----------

UILabel  *navTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];  //0 0 320 10

navTitleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
navTitleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
navTitleLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
navTitleLabel.text = @"IMG";
[navTitleLabel setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"BullettoKilla" size:16]];

self.navigationItem.titleView = navTitleLabel;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is the width `320`,  `navigationItem` auto adjust with the items beside it.. try using lesser value..

Comment: Wow this was a really stupid question. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [0yeoj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4903563/0yeoj) you have set the item width to 320. Try something smaller.

Answer (score -1):

Try this
`UILabel  *navTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 40)];`